# How to create array name after value of variable

Tags: ruby, variables

I'm trying to create some arrays in some threads and name them after a fixnum between 1 and 30 like the following:

```
times = 30
n=0
thread = []
while n < times
  thread << Thread.new(n)  {|x|
    array#{x} = Array.new()
    ... 
  }
end
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This is definitely a time to consider what you are doing and why. Variable names are for humans. The computer doesn't care (and will munge the name you give it).


Store this information in a collection(Array, Hash...). An array even has the benefit of number based index's, which seems to be what you want to do.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I don't mean to do that in purpose but didn't realize there's a way as you and gmalette addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby does not allow you to create variable names from strings in the same way that PHP does. In a case such as this you could use an array or a hash instead.

```
times = 30
n=0

arrays = []
thread = []

while n < times

  thread << Thread.new(n)  {|x|

    arrays[x] = Array.new()
    ... 
  }
end
```

You can also use more rubyish constructs instead of while, such as `Fixnum#times`.

```
arrays = []
threads = 30.times.map do |n|
  Thread.new do
    arrays[x] = Array.new
    # ...
  end
end

> arrays
#=> [[], [], [], ....]
> threads
#=> [#<Thread:0x007fe3f22a2320 dead>, #<Thread:0x007fe3f22a2208 dead>, ...]
```

Comment: thanks for giving out the code. And yes, I should work on how to think in ruby way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using instance variables rather than local variables, you can do what you are trying to do (whether it is a good idea to design code in this way is another question).

```
1.upto(times) do |i|
  instance_variable_set("@array#{i}".to_sym, [])
end
```